# Gradient of an angle

Tags: geometry, vectors, vector-analysis

We have three points labeled 1, 2 and 3 and an angle in the following image.

[image]

It is easy to show that the gradient of $\theta$ with respect to the position of the point 1 (i.e. when the other two points are fixed in space) is
$$ \boldsymbol{\nabla}_1 \theta = \frac{1}{r_{12}} \hat{\boldsymbol{\mathrm{u}}}_1,$$
where $r_{12}$ is the magnitude of the vector $\boldsymbol{\mathrm{r}}_{12} \equiv \boldsymbol{\mathrm{r}}_1 - \boldsymbol{\mathrm{r}}_2$, and $\hat{\boldsymbol{\mathrm{u}}}_1$ is the unit vector perpendicular to $\boldsymbol{\mathrm{r}}_{12}$ and in the plane that includes the three points. Similarly, the gradient of $\theta$ with respect to the position of the point 3 can be written as
$$ \boldsymbol{\nabla}_3 \theta = \frac{1}{r_{32}} \hat{\boldsymbol{\mathrm{u}}}_3.$$
Now, I'm looking for an expression for the gradient of $\theta$ with respect to the position of the point 2. Based on some insight from physics, I guess that the relation $\boldsymbol{\nabla}_1 \theta + \boldsymbol{\nabla}_2 \theta + \boldsymbol{\nabla}_3 \theta = 0$ holds here, though I haven't proved it mathematically.

Comment: What is the reference point you use here? If it is 2 than any vector is good/bad - its length is 0.

Comment: @Moti, what do you mean by "reference point"?

Comment: You use 1,2 and 1,3 so 2,...?

Comment: @Moti, as the image shows, the point 2 is the vertex of the angle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the relation

$$\cos(\theta)=\frac{\boldsymbol{\mathrm{r}}_{12}\cdot\boldsymbol{\mathrm{r}}_{32}}{r_{12}r_{32}},$$

I just derived the following relations:

$$\boldsymbol{\nabla}_1 \theta = \frac{1}{r_{12}} \frac{\cos(\theta)\hat{\boldsymbol{\mathrm{r}}}_{12}-\hat{\boldsymbol{\mathrm{r}}}_{32}}{\sin(\theta)},$$

$$\boldsymbol{\nabla}_3 \theta = \frac{1}{r_{32}} \frac{\cos(\theta)\hat{\boldsymbol{\mathrm{r}}}_{32}-\hat{\boldsymbol{\mathrm{r}}}_{12}}{\sin(\theta)},$$
and

$$\boldsymbol{\nabla}_1 \theta + \boldsymbol{\nabla}_2 \theta + \boldsymbol{\nabla}_3 \theta = 0.$$

Boldface letters with a hat ($\hat{}$) are unit vectors.